# UIMA ConceptMapper not finding dictionary terms in document

Tags: uima

I'm a new user of UIMA ConceptMapper.  Running in debug mode, i can see that the dictionary has some items loaded, but the dict.getEntries(word) call from processTokenList() always returns null. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A few hints:

- make sure your dictionary has some items loaded
- create a smaller dictionary with 2-3 terms to test on 2-3 words